# Couchbase bulk retrieving multiple keys in Java

Tags: java, couchbase, rx-java

In couchbase, consider a document has a field which contains a set of keys referencing other documents

```json
{
    "some_ids": ["otherdoc1", "otherdoc2", "otherdoc3"]
}
```

Which one of these 2 solutions for retrieving all doc in `some_ids` field gives the best performance?

1. [Batching with RxJava](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.0/documents-bulk.html)

   ```
   List<JsonDocument> foundDocs = Observable
   .just("otherdoc1", "otherdoc2", "otherdoc3")
   .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
       @Override
       public Observable<JsonDocument> call(String id) {
           return bucket.async().get(id);
       }
   })
   .toList()
   .toBlocking()
   .single();
   ```
2. Create a design view, then retrieve a subset of its index with `startKey` and `endKey`

   ```
   // Map function
   function(doc, meta) {
       if (doc.type == 'otherdoc') {
           emit(meta.id, doc);
       }
   }

   // ViewQuery (in a java method)
   ViewQuery.from('designOther', 'viewOther')
     .startKey('otherdoc1')
     .endKey('otherdoc2');
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Couchbase, when you know the key, the SDK knows which node to ask for that key (through hashing). On the other hand, querying a view implies the view engine to contact every node in the cluster.

So direct get && batching in RxJava, since you know the key(s), will save you additional round-trips and should end up the better performer!